# Programmatically retrieve the categories that can be assigned to pages in Episerver

Tags: c#, content-management-system, categories, episerver

Does anyone have an idea of how to programmatically retrieve the categories that can be assigned to pages in **Episerver**? **C#** is the programming language that I am using but an example in VB will do as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're after all the categories defined in the CMS, then start with fetching the root category first and all it's children.

```
Category rootCategory = Category.GetRoot();
CategoryCollection childCategories = rootCategory.Categories;
foreach (Category category in childCategories)
{
    // do whatever
}
```

If you only want to retrieve categories selected on the current page, then iterate through the Category property on the current page. It returns a CategoryList object which contains the Ids of the selected categories.

```
foreach (int catId in CurrentPage.Category)
{
    Category category = Category.Find(catId);
    // do whatever
}
```

Comment: `Category.GetRoot()` is obsolete as per Episerver 9.0

Answer (score 2):

Since `Category.GetRoot()` is marked as obsolete, this solution is more proper as per Episerver 9:

```
var categoryRepo = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<CategoryRepository>();
var rootCategory = categoryRepo.GetRoot();
CategoryCollection childCategories = rootCategory.Categories;
foreach (Category category in childCategories)
{
// do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the EPiServer.DataAbstraction.Category class. A good place to start would be the Category.GetRoot() method:

http://world.episerver.com/Documentation/Class-library/?documentId=cms/7/0ace72d5-11cd-b5cc-4dbe-af38a401f528

there are code examples on this page as well:

http://world.episerver.com/Documentation/Class-library/?documentId=cms/7/dbaa2f15-e227-1d1c-5142-2f245dd3e664